# How does Google make his border?

Tags: html, css, border

I was on the google news page and I was wondering how do google make his border around each sections, because I can't find in the inspector any element with a border property. I find those borders very thin and I think it is not with the border property with CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you inspect well, then you will see its a `box-shadow` instead of border, Here is what they used in their css, Please check again,

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
background-color: #fff;
```

Hint: check for class `.lPV2Xe`

Answer (score 0):

Because this is not a border. It's a box-shadow.

this effect can be created by

```
.card {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}
.card:hover{ 
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px 0 grey;
-webkit-transition:  box-shadow .3s ease-in;
}
```

and create a div with the class card.
found a similar pen [Link to example](https://codepen.io/Sarathkumar/pen/LVgmKJ)